# Maximize button does not work using Tkinter in RHEL5

Tags: python, tkinter, rhel5, maximize-window

I created a minimal Tkinter GUI as follows:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Everything is fine if I run the above code on RHEL5, except that the maximize button does not work properly(resizing is available). If I click the button, the window does not expand to occupy the whole screen. And I belive this issue is platform-specific, because there is no such issue for the same code on Windows.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Is there any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Fluxbox.  Try putting something in root like a label so it has something to display.  Probably won't make any difference but worth a try.